# How to approach a bag-of-words classification when each word has a 'loudness' parameter?

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

Suppose that I want to perform a binary classification on voice data, classifying sentences as having a positive/neutral or negative sentiment.The language I'm working with only has 50 words total and my imaginary speech-to-text algorithm transcribes each word perfectly, also measuring the volume at which it was spoken. Ideally, given the appropriate training set, my algorithm would correctly classify "Why did you do this?" and "WHY DID YOU DO THIS?!" as expressing opposite sentiments. I'm a bit at loss regarding what class of ML algorithms can handle such a problem and would very much appreciate any suggestions.